# How to solve STM32CubeMX keil error?

Tags: stm32cubemx, keil

I have installed keil v5 and installed STM32 package.
When I start the STM32 project and add  the Software components
[image: Error description]

Here is the directory 
[image]

Comment: Stm32 cube is a distinct piece of software which you seem to have not installed

Comment: I am creating a project from stm32f205RGTX .when I add startup file and CMSIS core it asks me to include stm32cubemx to start a project if not it produces an error.

Comment: Again you have not installed it... If you want to go this route it seems you need to.  These kind of silly tools get quickly left by the wayside in the real world, ultimately MCU software needs to fit into a company's practices just like all the rest of their software, but chip companies still think its 1990.